# Problem while decrypting Hill cipher

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, matrix-multiplication, hill-cipher

I have a plaintext "monday" and ciphertext "IKTIWM" and $m=2$.
I want to find the key of the Hill cipher.

I made a matrix 
$$ \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} m \\ o \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I \\ K \end{bmatrix} \pmod{26}$$

$X=\{\{m,o\},\{n,d\}\}$, $Y=\{\{I,K\},\{T,I\} \}$, I want to find $X \times K=Y$.

I will multiply this equation with inverse($X$).

But for the modulo inverse you need $gcd$(determinant($X), 26) =1$ . Which is not happening here.

Comment: I am making a matrix X={ {m,o}, {nd} },Y={ {I,K} ,{T,I} },I want to find X*K=Y;

Comment: I edited it.I don't know how to write a matrix here.

Comment: Hint: not all systems of 6 equations with 4 unknowns have a unique solution. Find them all.

Comment: these are the equations. 12a + 14b = 8 , 12c + 14d = 10 ,13a + 3d = 19 ,13c + 3d = 8 , 24b=22 , 24d= 12. I have replaced a1 with a , a2 with b , a3 with c , a4 with d. Can we solve them?

Comment: you are right. But can you help me solve it?

Comment: I feel They are not solvable.

Comment: you are right. But the reason why I am telling this is that GCD(determinat,26) ≠ 1.

Comment: use last equation to derive that $b = 13 n +2$ and that is $b$ is either 2 or 15.

Comment: @Manoharsinh Rana: your third equation should be 13a + 3**b** = 19. And all these equations are modulo 26. Yes you can solve that system, just not uniquely modulo 26. One systematic option is to rewrite that system modulo 13, and modulo 2, then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @fgrieu can you explain it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These modular equations are not *uniquely* solvable:

$$\begin{bmatrix}7&2\\ 10& 20\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}7&2\\ 23& 7\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}20&15\\ 10& 20\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}20&15\\ 23& 7\end{bmatrix}$$

are all the $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$  would transform 'monday' to `IKTIWM`, the first and third have even determinant so are not invertible so the second or the fourth candidate encryption matrix is the correct one: invert them and check the rest of the text which is one is actually correct.